# How to toggle p text Overflow when hitting a Button?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm trying to make `#showtext` act as a button that toggles the Text-Overflow of the `.entry-summary p`. I also really want it to show an ellipsis when the overflow is hidden. If anyone can please let me know why my code isn't working that would be very appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/d2tzc8wh/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#showText').toggle(function() {
    $(".entry-summary p").css('overflow', 'visible');
  }, function() {
    $(".entry-summary p").css('overflow', 'hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
.entry-summary p {
  height: 60px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
  word-break: break-all !important;
  white-space: normal !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="entry-summary">
  <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
    one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of “de Finibus Bonorum
    et Malorum” (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, “Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..”, comes from a line in section
    1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from “de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum” by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by
    English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. <a class="g1-link g1-link-more" href="https://example.com/">More</a></p>
</div>
<br><br>
<div id="showText">
  ClickMe
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This CSS would help you,

```css
.entry-summary p {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  /* white-space: nowrap; */
}
```

Toggle the white-space property on click of button to show it as ellipsis or as full-text using jquery or JS.